# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client with Proxy User has error ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: c#, oracle, odac, oracle-manageddataaccess

I have a project which connects (just fine) to Oracle via ODAC, `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` in .NET.  I would like to switch it to use `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`, but it gives an error `ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`.  I know the error happens when I connect/login as a "Proxy User", because it works (no error) when I remove the proxy user info from my connection string, but then I can't use the tables, SPs, packages that I need.

As a developer I need to login with "Proxy User" to impersonate several different back-end jobs, because I can't/won't get the passwords for those accounts.  The (proxy/impersonate) technique works nicely with un-managed `DataAccess` (which is a big pain to support) but I can't get it to work with `ManagedDataAccess`.

Here is my code:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  { // I need to impersonate the [reportbot] account to use that schema
    string constr = "User Id=developer2[reportbot];Password=Wysiwyg.12345;Data Source=ProdJobDb;";
    string ProviderName = "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client";

    DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(ProviderName);

    using (DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
      try
      {
        conn.ConnectionString = constr;
        conn.Open();
        //run SPs that [ReportBot] has access to, but dev contractor accounts don't
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); //breakpoint here F9
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: have you tried to use `Proxy User Id` to specify the user on behalf you are connecting to ?

Comment: If I use `Proxy User Id` without the `Proxy Password`, it gives a different error. The reason I am Proxying the account is because they don't want me (or other devs) to have the password(s) for the accounts that we are proxying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/odpnt/featConnecting.html#GUID-EC0754B1-367C-409D-A495-AE5BA9634B65) suggest the following connection string

> // Connecting using proxy authentication

```
con.ConnectionString = "User Id=scott;Password=tiger;" + 
  "Data Source=oracle;Proxy User Id=appserver;Proxy Password=eagle; ";
```

Based on your input is

```
 real user     reportbot  (you have no password)
 proxy user    developer2 (you have password)
```

so the connection string to be used is

```
 "User Id=reportbot;Proxy User Id=developer2;Proxy Password=<your delevoper pwd>;Data Source=ProdJobDb;";
```

Comment: The reason I am Proxying the account is because they don't want me (or other devs) to have the password(s) for the accounts that we are proxying.  If I omit the `Proxy Password`, it gives a different error.

Comment: The point is, you may omit the  the `Password` of the database `User`. You *must* provide the `Proxy Password`. @tgolisch If you pass the User Password in the *proxy authentication* you'll get the `ORA-01017`

Comment: It is nice to hear about this alternative approach, but I don't have the proxy password.  I'm not as interested in understanding why I get an error. I really want a solution, how to get this working. It works with un-managed, without the Proxy Password. There must be a way, with Managed (without having the proxy password).

Comment: Password of which user do you have? `developer2` or  `reportbot`? Note that `developer2` is the *proxy user*, if you have password for it, which I assume you should pass it as a parameter `Proxy Password` @tgolisch

Comment: I am the developer.  I login as `User Id=Developer1[reportbot];` So I can use SPs and packages which belong to reportbot. I don't have the password for reportbot.

Comment: Well based on the link provided in my answer, I'd use this connection string @tgolisch: `"User Id=reportbot;Proxy User Id=developer2;Proxy Password=<your delevoper pwd>;Data Source=ProdJobDb;";`

Comment: Please change your answer to this, so I can mark it.  Thank you!

Comment: @tgolisch did you make it work? I am facing the same issue. Due to compliance requirement, we are going to use oracle wallet and proxy authentication. Dotnet framework application works fine but dotnet core application is throwing same error as yours. The whole purpose is to not have password in connection string.

Comment: @MuqadarAli Yes. Using my user ID as the "Proxy User ID" and my password as the "Proxy Password". I can impersonate another account (show above as the "User Id").  I was using Dotnet framework, not dotnet core.

Comment: @tgolisch Did you make it work? Any suggestions or alternatives to this?

Comment: @MuqadarAli Yes. I got this working with Dotnet framework but not core. Just open another question on stackoverflow. I got a pretty good response. Your question could help others too.

Comment: @tgolisch thanks, I will do that.

Comment: I have asked the same question but for dot-net core (.Net5/6) applications. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70302473/oracle-manageddataaccess-core-3-21-41-oracle-wallet-with-proxy-user-has-error